# Maximum Sort of a Simple One-way List

Tags: c++, list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to do the **Maximum Sort** of a **Simple One-way List**. However my program has some bugs in it, which I can't figure out what it is. 
It behaves strange because sometimes it works well to a point where it just stop working but i see `return 0` (for example: I give the list of `1234` and I get back `3412`), sometimes it working to a point, then goes to an infinte loop. (for example: case of `12345` it put `5`, `4` and `3` the the 1st place and then infinite loop). 
The problem is probably in the `list::remMax()` or in the `maxRend()`. 

My code:

```
struct chain
{
    char key;
    chain *next;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////

class list
{
private:
    chain *L, **act;

public:
    list() {
        L=NULL;
        act=&L;
    }

    ~list() {
        chain *p;
        while(L) {
            p=L;
            L=L->next;
            delete []p;
        }
    }

    enum ERROR {endErr, memErr};

    void first() {act=&L;};
    void next() {
        if(*act!=NULL) {
            act=&(*act)->next;
        } else throw endErr;
    }
    bool end() {return *act==NULL;}
    bool oneEIn() {return L->next==NULL;} //list contains only 1 element
    bool twoEIn() {return L->next->next==NULL;} //list contains 2 elements
    void addE(char x) {
        chain *p=new(nothrow) chain;
        if(p == NULL) throw memErr;
        p->key=x;
        p->next=*act;
        *act=p;
    }
    chain* remMax(chain *H) {
        if(!oneEIn()) {
            chain *qe, *q, *Mpe, *Mp;
            if(twoEIn()) {
                Mp = H;
                q = Mp->next;
                if(q->key > Mp->key) {
                    Mp->next=q->next;
                    return q;
                } else {
                    H=q;
                    Mp->next=NULL;
                    return Mp;
                }
            } else {
                Mp=H;
                q=Mp->next;
                Mpe = H;
                qe = Mp;
                while(q != NULL) {
                    if(Mpe->key > Mp->key) Mp = Mpe;
                    if(q->key > Mp->key) {
                        Mp=q;
                        Mpe=qe;
                    }
                    qe=q;
                    q=q->next;
                }
                if(Mpe == Mp) H=Mp->next;
                else {
                    Mpe->next = Mp->next;
                }
                Mp->next=NULL;
                return Mp;
            }
        } else {
            chain *Mp;
            Mp = H;
            H = NULL;
            return Mp;
        }
    }
    void inE(chain *Mp) {
        first();
        Mp->next = *act;
        addE(Mp->key);
    }
    chain* getFirst() {return L;}

    void printList() {
        chain *p=L;
        while(p != NULL) {
            putchar(p->key);
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
};

///////////////////////////////////

void makeList(list& L) {
    char c;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n') {
        L.addE(c);
        L.next();
    }
}

void maxRend(list& L) {
    if(!L.oneEIn()) {
        chain *H, *Mp;
        H=L.getFirst();

        while(H != NULL) {
            cout<<"1.while\n";
            Mp = L.remMax(H);

            L.inE(Mp);
            cout<<"putIn: "<<Mp->key<<endl;
            H=H->next;
            L.printList();
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"\nSorted list: ";
        L.printList();
    } else L.printList();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    list L;
    makeList(L);

    maxRend(L);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have gone out of your way to make your code hard to read. This makes it easier for bugs to hide. I recommend giving your variables descriptive names and spacing the code out a bit more.

Comment: The best way to troubleshoot a linked list (or any graph) is to draw the sucker. Sometimes you have to draw out the operation step by step. Follow your coded instructions on a piece of paper and see if you can draw the chain you want. If you can't you should be able to see where you went astray as you do it and have a pretty good idea of what you should have done instead.

Comment: Also take advantage of the debugger that should have come with your development tools. The debugger will allow you to step through your program and watch what it does as it does it. If it doesn't match the drawings you made, you've just found a bug.

Comment: @user4581301 Mp is the max pointer, Mpe is the previous element from the list, q is the element, which go thru the list and compare with Mp and qe is the previous element of q.
Also I tried to draw it to a paper and that s why I dont understand why is it stop somewhere at the middle.

Comment: Now is the time to pull the debugger in. Fire up the program in the debugger and start stepping. As soon as the debugger shows you something you didn't expect, you see the program do something that you didn't draw, stop and figure out why.